# How to include NetBeans Platform Source code into module dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

I am debugging a NetBeans Platform application. 
I have downloaded the NetBeans Platform source code .zip file. 
I would really really like to attach the source code to the debugger so that I can seamlessly jump to internal NB source code.

Normally I would edit the Library configuration to tell NB where to find the source code, and it would just work. 
However this is not possible for NetBeans Modules; when I look at the Utilities API module dependency it does not look like a normal NB library and there is nowhere to add in the source code.

I suspect that if I were to rebuild my project using Maven this would work automatically.
But thats a terrible reason to switch to maven.

How can I get the NB Platform Source code included into my Module Dependencies ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the zip to the 'Source' window.

To open the Sources window

- Select the 'Debugging->Sources' item
  from the Windows menu

To add the zip file to the sources...

- right click somewhere in the window.
- select 'Add Source Root' from the menu that appears
  [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/87c4e3fc8c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/87c4e3fc8c.png)

Comment: That is (almost) perfect. 
I still have to add the NetBeans src directories by hand. 
But it would be churlish to complain :)

Thanks very much